# What do the anti-symmetric matrices in quantum mechanics represent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, lie-algebra, linear-algebra, matrix-elements

Anti-symmetric matrices have a trace 0. One of the three Pauli matrices,  $\sigma_y$ is anti-symmetric. I also see anti-symmetric matrices pop up in Relativity.

So is there any special conceptual physical distinction between operators whose matrix representation is anti-symmetric as opposed to the symmetric representations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, the commutator of two antisymmetric (anti-Hermitian) matrices is again an antisymmetric (anti-Hermitian) matrix, i.e. antisymmetric (anti-Hermitian) matrices form a [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra), respectively. Lie algebras play important roles in all areas of physics, e.g. as a set of generators of continuous symmetry, so they are likely to pop up everywhere.

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: So is it that these antisymmetric matrices are generators of continuous symmetries?

Comment: Yes, if it is an [orthogonal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group).

Comment: I see. Appreciate for clearing it up